# useState Hook does not working on firs time of to call the function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Hi everybody im triying to send a initial value status to childreen component from propsbut the problem is what i try to call a funtion for update the state the hook does not updating my state on the first call but the funtcion is working (a axios petition) if i try erase the inital state from propsthis really work but i need a initial state...

My children method:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        if(props.isdisabled == 1){
            setDisabled(true)
        } else{
            setDisabled(false)
        }
    }, [setDisabled]);
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState()

    const enableddisabled = async() =>{
        const habilitar = await user.habilitardeshabilitarbuque(props.id)
        switch(habilitar){
            case true:
                setDisabled(true)
                console.log(false)
                
            break;
            case false:
                setDisabled(false)
            break;
        }
    }
    return (
```

```js
                <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={()=>{enableddisabled()}}
                    style={{ marginLeft: 0 }}>
                    <View style={[my.button, my.is_rounded,{backgroundColor: disabled == true ? '#57c2e6' : '#c7c7c7'}]}>
                        {disabled == true
                        ?
                        <Text style={[my.button_text, { fontSize: 13 }]}>
                        Deshabilitar
                        </Text>
                        :
                        <Text style={[my.button_text, { fontSize: 13 }]}>
                            Habilitar
                            </Text>

                        }
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
```

and my parent component:

```js
return usuarios.map((data, index) => {
    const columncolor = color(index)
    const trye = disabled(data.isdisabled)
    console.log(data.isdisabled)
    return (
        <ScrollItems
            color={columncolor}
            id={data.id}
            index={index}
            username={data.username}
            nombre={data.nombre}
            apellido={data.apellido}
            email={data.mail}
            doubleCheck={data.doublecheck}
            deletealerta={deletealerta}
            deletebuquebyindex={deleteusuariobyindex}
            editar={editarusuario}
            isdisabled={trye}
        />
    )
})
```

thanks, really thanks for the help

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that the isdisabled  property from the parent is 1?

Comment: yes can to be 1 or 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(props.isdisabled); // set default value

useEffect(() => {
        … <———— Remove this particular code —>
}, [setDisabled]); <———— Change `setDisabled` to `disabled` here —>
 
const enableddisabled = async() =>{
  const habilitar = await user.habilitardeshabilitarbuque(props.id)
  setDisabled(habilitar); <———— Replace `switch` code to this line only —>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but have you tried
setting the initial value of your state hook to
props.isdisabled

Comment: yes, before i try set the initial state directly but does not work and finding at internet i believed whit the current way 
would work